# is serialized form string secure

Tags: php, ajax, forms, serialization

I use full of ajax requests in my mini networking site . whenever i want to supply some input like the user inputted text along with some important ids , i put them in a form and use '.serialize' to make it as a string and send it through '.getJSON' or '.post' . in the receiving php file 'parse_str' is used to make them seperate variables . 
Is this whole process secure ? I didnt have any other better idea . So please reply regarding this

Comment: i use htmlspecialchars for user inputted text and then i include them in the form as hidden variable's value . Do u have any better idea?

Comment: What do you mean by **"secure"**? Secure in what way?

Comment: secure in the sense, i wnat to know whether am i creating more possibilities than it should be for some hacker to malfunction my site or even any big damages

Answer (score 1):

No this is not secure.

For example, the serialized string for a password form could be in the format "username=hello&password=world" i.e. the serialized form string is still in plain text and can be sniffed in packets..

Be sure to get an SSL certificate and use HTTPS for any user authentication.

Comment: ok , so apart from login page , is this alrite for other general ajax requests that carry user inputted status messages and additional info ?

Comment: do u have any other idea of transporting the user typed status msgs and extra info other than sending them in hidden form ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with security in user-submitted content is that it might contain code that, if not escaped properly, could cause problems. If you're submitting the information to a MySQL server, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: i use htmlspecialchars for user inputted text and then i include them in the form as hidden variable's value . Do u have any better idea?